# Which available operating systems for the Pi come with OpenOffice and paint programs?

Tags: operating-systems

I'm collecting RPi OS, and I want to know if there exists an OS that already comes with office tools like OpenOffice Writer not such notepad and something to paint or draw things.
Thank you.

__ And english isn't my mother language, i use translator when i can but not always.__

Comment: They are all in all of the Raspberry Pi OS repositories.

Comment: Two different people have now (independently) edited your title; you rejected mine but *please do not reject this one.*  The point of stack exchange is *not* for people to ask casual questions with meaningless junk titles.  Use IRC if that is all the effort you can muster.

Comment: If so say this as well. But
the problem is that I do
not have the answer that I get ...
Since the people are already
responding things that differ from
the real objective of the topic and
some even did the favor of begin
voting to delete the topic, I do not
in any union side except against me.
In any case I would not exchange of
words or discussion, just thought
that when needing to help could
have recourse to this site. I will not
post more to avoid problems :/

Comment: @Edilson If you are not getting the answers you want, then maybe you need to explain yourself better. Example: you say you want "OpenOffice Writer" and "something to paint or draw things".  Several people have referred you to *LibreOffice* (which is EXACTLY the same thing, LOOK IT UP!) and *gimp*, which is a draw and paint tool.  Yet now you complain *"I do not have the answer...people are already responding to things that differ from the real objective"*!!! How can anyone make sense of what it is that you want?

Comment: What i want is know if there exists an OS that have programs like this already installed.
A program "as" OpenOffice writer.
All it because my bad english

Answer (score 3):

If they are not already installed, you can easily install out of the repositories by running the command `sudo apt-get install libreoffice` and for gimp, a photoshop like program, `sudo apt-get install gimp`.  They are actually easier to install in *nix than in Windows!

A list (It may or may not be complete) of available software can be found at [Raspberry Connect](http://www.raspberryconnect.com/raspbian-packages-list)

Comment: I've got an wifi internet and i've installed some programs that i need except the word processor like OpenOffice because it is too big (101mb) and my internet just have 100mb of limit. Did you have another sugestion for one else word processor with good graphic interface and good tools under of 20mb ? 
-- my english isn't good, then please sorry if you can't understand --

Comment: Look into abiword.  I don't know exactly how big it is, but it is smaller than libreoffice.

Comment: I already get it is 11~12MB.
Is perfect for what i've searched.
Thank you once more.

Answer (score 1):

Libreoffice, the fork of openOffice more commonly used on linux, is in raspbian, as is [gimp](http://www.gimp.org/).  They should also both be in pidora.